# Visual Studio 2012: Remote and local debugging of a Windows Store app at the same time

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I am developing a networked Windows Store app.

Is it possible to remotely and locally debug a Windows Store app using the same instance of Visual Studio?

I have successfully set up remote debugging using a VM on my local machine.

I have a few alternatives, but I just want to know if this is currently possible. One of them is running them on multiple instances of VS. Another is installing VS on the remote machine and debug it locally as normal. (which I don't want to do as much as possible because it's really a waste of disk space)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do this:

1. Build your Windows Store App in Visual Studio.
2. Select **Local Machine** on debugger toolbar. Right click on your Windows Store App Project in **Solution Explorer** -> Click **Deploy**. This will deploy latest App on Local Machine.
3. Select **Remote Machine** on debugger toolbar. Right click on your Windows Store App Project in Solution Explorer -> Click **Deploy**. This will deploy latest App on Remote Machine.
4. In Visual Studio click on **Debug** menu -> **Debug Installed App Package**. Choose Local 
   Machine (by default) -> find your application and click **Debug**.
5. Launch **Remote Debugger** on Remote Machine.
6. The same step as 4 above, but for Remote machine. In Visual Studio click on **Debug** menu -> **Debug Installed App Package**. Choose Remote Machine -> find your application and click **Debug**.

One issue you can meet:

I tried this approach with different architectures of Remote (ARM) And Local (x64) machine. My guess that each time you do **Deploy** - Visual Studio can rebuild your application. So in case if you will use the same architecture for Remote and Local - only for one of them you can load symbols (just try it). If you will meet this situation - you can workaround it with two ways:

- Use x64 for Local Machine and x86 for remote (or vice versa). So each build / deploy will be independent.
- Make a Windows Store Package for Testing. Deploy it manually on both machine and start from 4.

Comment: Thanks. I do think this is the way to go, given the general question I asked.

I just encountered a problem where the VM has a reduced screen resolution where I can't run WS apps. But that's that.